# Simple calculus question about differentiation

Tags: calculus

I am confusing myself on what seems like a very simple question:

If $x=\frac{a^\phi}{b}$ and $y=\frac{a}{b}$, then what is $\frac{dx}{dy}$?

I tried writing $x=y^\phi b^{\phi-1}$ and then using the chain and product rules to get $\frac{dx}{dy}=\phi y^{\phi-1}b^{\phi-1} + y^\phi (\phi-1)b^{\phi-2}\frac{db}{dy}$. In turn, I can write $\frac{db}{dy}$ in terms of $\frac{da}{dy}$, but this doesn't seem to get me closer to a final expression. Is this as far as the result can be simplified, or am I missing something?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

(And $a, b, \phi\in\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: I need a clarification. Are you assuming $a, b, \phi$ alla as variables? or only $a$ and $b$ with \phi as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$dx=\frac{(\phi a^{\phi-1}da+\log a\,a^\phi\,d\phi)b-a^\phi db}{b^2}$$

and

$$dy=\frac{da\,b-a\,db}{b^2}$$

so that

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{\phi a^{\phi-1}b\,da+\log a\,a^\phi b\,d\phi-a^\phi db}{da\,b-a\,db}.$$

If there are no dependencies between $a,b,\phi$, this is about all you can say.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think to differentiate $\phi$.

Comment: @js86: well,if you know that it's a constant, $d\phi$ vanishes. But this wans't said.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.